# ImageIO.read throws a java.lang.NullPointerException even when file at the file path exists. How to fix this?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

```
File image = new File("/path/to/image/file");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(fis);
int height = originalImage.getHeight();
```

---

Exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at package.classfile.main(classfile.java:23)
```

Comment: on which line  you are getting null pointer ?

Comment: Could you provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: Is `image` being created? `ImageIO.read` may require a specific type of file. From the docs:  "Image I/O has built-in support for GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP. Image I/O is also extensible so that developers or administrators can "plug-in" support for additional formats. For example, plug-ins for TIFF and JPEG 2000 are separately available."

Comment: Surely the null pointer is from ImageIO.read(fis). 
Javadocs: "If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned."
Try to check the file first: image.exists()

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).